# How to change SQLyog date format

Tags: javascript, sql, jsp, date, sqlyog

I am using SQLyog for my database.I have a date field in my HTML which inputs date from user in dd/mm/yyy format. My requirement is to store date from date field in dd/mm/yyyy format. SQLyog is not allowing me to do this, SQLyog only permits dates in format yyyy-mm-dd. Suggest some easy way to achieve dd/mm/yyyy format. 
(I am implementing this in jsp)

Also tell a regular expression for validation of date format dd/mm/yyyy.

Kind regards.

Comment: But why u need to cahnge the formate of sqlyog. You can also store date in yyyy-mm-dd format from jsp.

Comment: @K.D yes i can , but i have mentioned that its my requirement to save date in this format !

Comment: So do you want a javascript function to output dd/mm/yyyyy from a Date object, to convert a string in that format to a Date, and to validate the resulting date?

Comment: RobG I want to store date from date field in DB in this dd/mm/yyy format. SQLyog is only accepting yyyy-mm-dd format . I also need a regular expression for dd/mm/yyyy format. This is it ! I have edit my post as well !